# Receipt absent data from the database store locator tutorial google - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3, php-7

I followed the google tutorial to create a store locator: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

I tried to show the error on the display but I do not get anything, the only positive thing that the creation of the static marker appears on screen, the motivation that the api key implementation is correct.

Unfortunately I can not understand what the absence of communication with the database depends on.

Which function could I use, to be able to have a clearer situation on which to go to work?

index.html:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Creating a Store Locator on Google Maps</title>
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
     * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div>
         <label for="raddressInput">Search location:</label>
         <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="15"/>
        <label for="radiusSelect">Radius:</label>
        <select id="radiusSelect" label="Radius">
          <option value="50" selected>50 kms</option>
          <option value="30">30 kms</option>
          <option value="20">20 kms</option>
          <option value="10">10 kms</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width: 10%; visibility: hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 90%"></div>

    <script>

            var map;
      var markers = [];
      var infoWindow;
      var locationSelect;

// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, 
    center: uluru,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

          searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton").onclick = searchLocations;
                    locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
          locationSelect.onchange = function() {
            var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            if (markerNum != "none"){
              google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
            }
          };
}
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      function searchLocations() {
  var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert(address + ' not found');
    }
  });
}


function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
     new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
     new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
     callback(request.responseText, request.status);
   }
 };

 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send(null);
}


function searchLocationsNear(center) {
  clearLocations();

  var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
  var searchUrl = 'storelocator.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
  var xml = parseXml(data);
  var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
    var id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
    var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
    var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
    var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

    createOption(name, distance, i);
    createMarker(latlng, name, address);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
 });
}


function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
  var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}


function createOption(name, distance, num) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = num;
  option.innerHTML = name;
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}


function clearLocations() {
  infoWindow.close();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers.length = 0;

  locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = "none";
  option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
  locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
}

       function parseXml(str) {
          if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            doc.loadXML(str);
            return doc;
          } else if (window.DOMParser) {
            return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str);
          }
       }

       function doNothing() {}
    </script>
        <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCbn9gIka8i-33HotlIor7GHMt2WEo_aAQ&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php:

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="ca2solution";
?>
```

storelocator.php

```
<?php
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name, address, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  real_escape_string($center_lat),
  real_escape_string($center_lng),
  real_escape_string($center_lat),
  real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = mysqli_num_rows($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: You should be using mysql_* functions, they are officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5 (released June 2013). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I went to replace: mysql_connect with mysqli_connect

then: mysql_select_db with mysqli_select_db

@mysql_fetch_assoc with mysqli_fetch_array

but still no result. this in the storelocator page of my question

Comment: you do not need `onload="initMap()"` is the `initMap` is defined as a callback to the script. The `mysql` api has been deprecated ( as already pointed out ), you do not need to nor should you call `$result = mysql_query($query);` twice and why use XML when JSON is easier, quicker and requires less overhead?

Comment: recapitolando I updated in my question the file storelocator.php but unfortunately the non-communication with the db persists, omit something?

Comment: i have only this 3 file. i Editi my index.html because i go to delete onload="initMap()"

Comment: Before trying to implement a whole script like that, why don't you try to debug step by step? Create a PHP page and try your MySQL connection, try to retrieve some data. Once this is working... try an AJAX call to your PHP page and see what you get, then... next step. Nobody can debug this for you. We don't have your DB, we don't know how your server is configured, etc. etc.

Comment: Did you follow the ["checking the XML works"](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator#checking-that-xml-output-works) portion of that tutorial?

Comment: i try but i don t know to implement this with a var javascript in my code

Comment: @upsidedown it s not important know how it s my db, in my question there is  a link for the tutorial, and in the tutorial there is the option for the db, if u read my question you can find this code is on my localhost. Very important for me. it's ho hard!

Answer (score -1):

I noticed a few things with the original code which were not right ( using `mysql`, error in `parseXml`, a search box which is not used and ... others ) so as I had a little spare time I had a play and put together a somewhat different version which, if studied and adapted, should help solve the issues faced.

An example table of the same structure......

```
mysql> describe markers;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lat     | float(10,6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lng     | float(10,6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type    | int(11)      | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

An example of the data.......

```
mysql> select * from markers limit 10;
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------+
| id | name                    | address                                                     | lat       | lng       | type |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------+
| 42 | Nathro 17 x 135m        | 1 Goynd Steading, Glenogil, Forfar, Angus DD8 3SW, UK       | 56.793251 | -2.862310 |    1 |
| 43 | Ark Hill - 8 x 81m      | 3 Dryburn Cottages, Glenogilvy, Forfar, Angus DD8 1UP, UK   | 56.570656 | -3.051173 |    1 |
| 44 | Dodd Hill - 5 x 125m    | 4 Backmuir Rd, Duntrune, Tealing, Dundee, Angus DD4 0PT, UK | 56.542511 | -2.905154 |    1 |
| 45 | Govals - 6 x 87m        | B9127, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK                                | 56.582321 | -2.950902 |    1 |
| 46 | Carsegownie - 1 x78m    | B9134, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK                                | 56.679512 | -2.806298 |    1 |
| 47 | North Tarbrax - 1 x 45m | 4 Nether Finlarg Farm Cottages, Forfar, Angus DD8 1XQ, UK   | 56.571445 | -2.924766 |    1 |
| 48 | The Carrach - 9 x 84m   | B951, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK                             | 56.693844 | -3.131382 |    1 |
| 49 | Glaxo - 2 x 132m        | 5 Meridian St, Montrose, Angus DD10 8DS, UK                 | 56.704315 | -2.466087 |    1 |
| 50 | Craignathro 1 x 24m     | Dundee Rd, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK                            | 56.624084 | -2.884898 |    1 |
| 51 | Craignathro 2 - 1x41m   | A90, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK                                  | 56.620872 | -2.880220 |    1 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

A mysql `Stored Procedure` which I had written previously - minor modification to suit this particular question/problem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spFindMarkers`(
    IN `param_name` VARCHAR(64),
    IN `param_lat` DOUBLE,
    IN `param_lng` DOUBLE,
    IN `param_radius` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'Find markers based upon given starting lat/lng, a name and a radius'
begin

    /* user supplied parameters / variables */
    declare lat double default 0;
    declare lng double default 0;
    declare radius integer default 0;
    declare _name varchar(64);

    /* default parameters / variables */
    declare earth_radius integer default 0;
    declare lon1 float;
    declare lat1 float;
    declare lon2 float;
    declare lat2 float;

    /* create variables from input parameters */
    set @lat=param_lat;
    set @lng=param_lng;
    set @radius=cast( param_radius as signed );
    set @earth_radius=3956;
    set @_name=cast(param_name as char character set utf8);

    /* internal variables ~ do not edit */
    set @lon1 = @lng - @radius/abs( cos( radians(@lat) ) * 69 );
    set @lon2 = @lng + @radius/abs( cos( radians(@lat) ) * 69 );
    set @lat1 = @lat - (@radius/69);
    set @lat2 = @lat + (@radius/69);


    select distinct 
        m.`id`,
        m.`name`,
        m.`address`,
        m.`lat`,
        m.`lng`,
        round( @earth_radius * 2 * asin( sqrt( power( sin( ( @lat - m.`lat` ) * pi() / 180 / 2 ), 2 ) + cos( @lat * pi() / 180 ) * cos( m.`lat` * pi() / 180 ) *power( sin( ( @lng - m.`lng` ) * pi() / 180 / 2 ), 2 ) ) ),2) as `distance`
    from `markers` m
    where   
        ( m.`lat` between @lat1 and @lat2 ) 
            and 
        ( m.`lng` between @lon1 and @lon2 )
    /*
        the `having` clause might not suit your requirements... edit as appropriate!
    */
    having `distance` <= @radius or `name` like concat( '%', @_name, '%' ) or `address` like concat( '%', @_name, '%' )
    order by `distance`
    /* 
        A dynamic limit is possible but causes many issues with the PHP prepared statement
        as you need to do a prepared statement within the stored procedure.
    */
    limit 0,20;
end
```

An example of the xml generated ( db dependant of course )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
  <marker id="230" name="Fletcherfield 2x45m turbines?" address="1 Dameye Farm Cottages, Logie, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8 5PR, UK" lat="56.660805" lng="-2.978641" distance="1.37"/>
  <marker id="143" name="Longbank Kirriemuir - height not known" address="2 Crieff Terrace, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8 4LU, UK" lat="56.693573" lng="-2.961416" distance="2.04"/>
  <marker id="229" name="Auchindorie 1x46m turbine" address="Auchindorie, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.651802" lng="-3.039208" distance="2.10"/>
  <marker id="97" name="Reedie Farm 2x45.6m turbines" address="A926, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.658123" lng="-3.055901" distance="2.31"/>
  <marker id="232" name="Cairnleith Farm 1x19.9m turbine" address="Ghenty, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8 5HF, UK" lat="56.669613" lng="-3.081222" distance="2.97"/>
  <marker id="87" name="Genty, Airlie 1x34.5m turbine" address="Ghenty, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.662685" lng="-3.084762" distance="3.20"/>
  <marker id="66" name="Cortachy - Gallow Hill 1 x 46m turbine" address="B955, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.731060" lng="-2.968154" distance="4.09"/>
  <marker id="99" name="Sprottie Fauld 20m turbine" address="A94, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.610363" lng="-3.037190" distance="4.65"/>
  <marker id="75" name="East Memus Farm 1x76.5m turbine" address="4 Church Terrace, Memus, Forfar, Angus DD8 3TY, UK" lat="56.731243" lng="-2.932820" distance="4.71"/>
  <marker id="58" name="South Leckaway 1x78m turbine" address="3 Mains of Brigton Cottages, Forfar, Angus DD8 1TH, UK" lat="56.621323" lng="-2.923994" distance="4.79"/>
  <marker id="145" name="Miltonbank Farm - height not known" address="B957, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.705330" lng="-2.886529" distance="4.90"/>
  <marker id="48" name="The Carrach - 9 x 84m turbines" address="B951, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.693844" lng="-3.131382" distance="5.02"/>
  <marker id="144" name="East Memus Farm 1x76.5m turbine 0.8MW" address="1 Goynd Steading, Glenogil, Forfar, Angus DD8 3SW, UK" lat="56.734554" lng="-2.922835" distance="5.12"/>
  <marker id="223" name="The Welton 2x47m turbines" address="B951, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.694519" lng="-3.134095" distance="5.13"/>
  <marker id="211" name="Kalulu House 1x45.8m turbine" address="1 Whig Street, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.711098" lng="-2.878921" distance="5.34"/>
  <marker id="124" name="W Mains of Whitewell 2x46m turbines" address="1 Whig St, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.705421" lng="-2.866838" distance="5.59"/>
  <marker id="50" name="Craignathro 1 x 24m turbine" address="Dundee Rd, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.624084" lng="-2.884898" distance="5.72"/>
  <marker id="85" name="Ladenford 1x 46.5 turbine" address="1 Craignathro Farm Cottages, Forfar, Angus DD8 2LE, UK" lat="56.628838" lng="-2.877588" distance="5.75"/>
  <marker id="128" name="Castleton of Eassie 3x25m turbines" address="A94, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.604778" lng="-3.086371" distance="5.79"/>
  <marker id="53" name="Lour Farm 1x35m turbine" address="Dundee Rd, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.628407" lng="-2.875971" distance="5.82"/>
</markers>
```

The PHP & HTML - combined for simplicity into one page for testing. Best practise when dealing with user-supplied data in combination with database access in PHP is to use a `prepared statement`, either in mysqli or PDO, to avoid sql injection attacks. The code below uses `PDO` for the database layer but could quite as easily have been done with `mysqli`.

The sql itself in this example is written as a `stored procedure` ( as seen above ), the map's initial viewport is centred on Scotland rather than Australia as my database primarily contains locations in and around the area shown. I found a couple of minor errors in the javascript but with luck corrected those here.

```
<?php
    /*
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495882/receipt-absent-data-from-the-database-store-locator-tutorial-google-php

        This PHP code emulates the code that would be used in `storelocator.php`
        and is presented inline for demo/test purposes only

    */

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty( $_GET['lat'] ) && !empty( $_GET['lng'] ) ){

        ob_clean();

        header( 'Content-type: text/plain' );
        $xml='no results';

        /* PDO Database connection */
        /*
            database connection could very easily be an external file
            called using `require` or `include` etc
        */
        $dbport =   3306;
        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root'; 
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
        $dbname =   'xxx';

        $options=array( 
            PDO::ATTR_CURSOR                    =>  PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT                =>  false,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY  =>  true,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES          =>  true,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND        =>  'SET NAMES \'utf8mb4\' COLLATE \'utf8mb4_unicode_ci\', @@sql_mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES, @@foreign_key_checks = 1'
        );

        /* generate db connection string and PDO connection object */
        $dsn='mysql:host='.$dbhost.';port='.$dbport.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=UTF8';
        $db = new PDO( $dsn, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $options );



        /* sql statement to call the stored procedure in a prepared statement */
        $sql='call `spFindMarkers`( :name, :lat, :lng, :radius );';

        /* create the prepared statement */
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );




        if( $stmt ){

            /* filter incoming GET variables */
            $args=array(
                'lat'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
                'lng'       =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
                'radius'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
                'limit'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
                'name'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
            );
            filter_input_array( INPUT_GET, $args );
            $_GET = array_filter( $_GET );

            /* create variables from GET parameters */
            extract( $_GET );



            /* create the SQL bound parameters array */
            $params=array(
                ':name'     =>  $name,
                ':lat'      =>  $lat,
                ':lng'      =>  $lng,
                ':radius'   =>  $radius
            );

            /* execute the prepared statement */
            $res = $stmt->execute( $params );


            if( $res ){
                /* Generate the XML response */
                $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
                $root = $dom->appendChild( $dom->createElement('markers') );

                /* process the recordset */
                while( $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
                    $marker = $dom->createElement('marker');
                    $marker->setAttribute( 'id', $rs->id );
                    $marker->setAttribute( 'name', urldecode( $rs->name ) );
                    $marker->setAttribute( 'address', urldecode( $rs->address ) );
                    $marker->setAttribute( 'lat', $rs->lat );
                    $marker->setAttribute( 'lng', $rs->lng );
                    $marker->setAttribute( 'distance', $rs->distance );
                    $root->appendChild( $marker );
                }

                $xml=$dom->saveXML();
                header( 'Content-type: application/xml' );
            }
        } else {
            $xml='error';
        }

        $dom = $root = $db = null;
        exit( $xml );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Creating a Store Locator on Google Maps</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            height:calc(100vh - 2.6rem);
            width:100%;
        }
        html, body {
            height:100vh;
            width:100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        form{
            height:2.5rem;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:row;
            flex-align:flex-start;
            justify-content:flex-start;
            align-items:center;
            background:gold;
            border-bottom:2px solid black;
            font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
        }
        form *{ padding:0.25rem;}
        option[selected]{background:gold;}
    </style>
    <script>
        var map;
        var marker;
        var circle;
        var markers = [];
        var infoWindow;
        var oSelect;


        function initMap() {
            var uluru = {
                lat: -25.344,
                lng: 131.036
            };
            var default_location = {
                lat:56.646577,
                lng:-2.888609
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10, 
                center: default_location,/* change to uluru ? */
                mapTypeId:'roadmap',
                mapTypeControlOptions:{ style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU }
            });

            /*
                https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/Google-Maps-API/2k3T5hwI5Ck/RRso0D2jB1oJ
                for icons....
            */
            marker = new google.maps.Marker( { position: default_location, map: map, icon:'//maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-pushpin.png' });
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


            oRadius=document.getElementById('radiusSelect');

            oBttn=document.getElementById('bttn');
            oBttn.onclick = searchLocations;

            oSelect=document.getElementById('locationSelect');
            oSelect.onchange=function(event){
                if( this.value != 'none' ){
                    oSelect.value=this.value;
                    google.maps.event.trigger( markers[ this.value ], 'click' );
                }
            };

            circle=createcircle( default_location, oRadius.value );
            oRadius.addEventListener( 'change',function(){
                circle.setRadius( this.value * 1000 );
            },false);
        }


        function searchLocations() {
            var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            if( address=='' ){
                alert('No point searching for a blank address now is there?');
                return false;
            }
            geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    searchLocationsNear( results[0].geometry.location );
                    marker.setPosition( results[0].geometry.location );
                    circle.setCenter( results[0].geometry.location );
                    circle.setMap( map );
                } else {
                    alert( address + ' not found' );
                }
            });
        }
        function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status==200 ) callback( this.responseText, this.status );
            };
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }
        const createcircle=function(position,radius){
            circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center:position,
                radius:parseFloat( radius ) * 1000,
                fillColor:'red',
                fillOpacity:0.05,
                strokeColor:'red',
                strokeWeight:1,
                clickable:true,
                geodesic:true,
                map:map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener( circle, 'click', function(e){
                this.setMap( null )
            }.bind( circle ) );

            return circle;
        }
        function searchLocationsNear( center ) {
            clearLocations();

            var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
            var name = document.getElementById('addressInput').value;
            var searchUrl = 'storelocator.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius+'&name='+name;

            /*
            *
            *
            *
            *
            *
            *
            *****************************************/
            /* !!! FOR TESTING ONLY - SAME PAGE !!! */

            searchUrl ='?lat='+center.lat()+'&lng='+center.lng()+'&radius='+radius+'&name='+name

            /* !!! FOR TESTING ONLY - SAME PAGE !!! */
            /*****************************************
            *
            *
            *
            *
            *
            *
            *
            */

            downloadUrl( searchUrl, function( data ) {
                var xml = parseXML( data );
                var nodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                if( nodes.length == 0 ){
                    alert('no results')
                    return;
                }

                for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) {
                    var node=nodes[i];

                    var id = node.getAttribute('id');
                    var name = node.getAttribute('name');
                    var name = node.getAttribute('name');
                    var address = node.getAttribute('address');
                    var distance = parseFloat(node.getAttribute('distance'));
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat( node.getAttribute('lat') ),
                        parseFloat( node.getAttribute('lng') )
                    );

                    createOption( name, distance, i, id );
                    createMarker( latlng, name, address, id );
                    bounds.extend( latlng );
                }
                map.fitBounds( bounds );
            });
        }
        function createMarker( latlng, name, address, rid ) {
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: latlng,
                rid:rid,
                icon:'//maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(event){
                infoWindow.setContent( html );
                infoWindow.open( map, this );
                oSelect.value=oSelect.querySelector('option[data-rid="'+this.rid+'"]').value;
            });
            markers.push( marker );
        }
        function createOption( name, distance, num, rid ) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = num;
                option.innerHTML = name;
                option.dataset.rid = rid;
            oSelect.appendChild( option );
        }
        function clearLocations() {
            infoWindow.close();
            for( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers.length = 0;

            oSelect.innerHTML = '';
            var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = 'none';
                option.innerHTML = 'See all results:';

            oSelect.appendChild(option);
            oSelect.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        const parseXML=function( xml ){
            try{
                if( window.ActiveXObject ){
                    let oParser=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                        oParser.loadXML( xml );
                    return oParser;
                } else {
                    let oParser = new DOMParser();
                    return oParser.parseFromString(xml,'application/xml');  
                }
            }catch( err ){
                console.log( err );
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCbn9gIka8i-33HotlIor7GHMt2WEo_aAQ&callback=initMap"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method='post'>
        <label for='raddressInput'>Search location:</label>
        <input type='text' id='addressInput' name='addressInput' size='15' value='kirrie' />

        <label for='radiusSelect'>Radius:</label>
        <select id='radiusSelect' name='radiusSelect' label='Radius'>
          <option value=100>100 kms
          <option value=90>90 kms
          <option value=80>80 kms
          <option value=70>70 kms
          <option value=60>60 kms
          <option value='50'>50 kms
          <option value=40>40 kms
          <option value='30'>30 kms
          <option value='20'>20 kms
          <option value='10' selected>10 kms
          <option value='5'>5 kms
          <option value='1'>1 kms
        </select>

        <input type='button' id='bttn' value='Search' />
        <select id='locationSelect' name='locationSelect' style='width: 10%; visibility: hidden'></select>
    </form>
    <div id='map'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :( ordinarily I'd be upset that someone downvoted     - a comment or two though perhaps would be nice?